# French slang equivalent of "chicken"

Tags: traduction, anglais, argot, enfants

You can call someone "chicken" or "chicken hearted" for being scared. Mind it, it's not coward which is serious. Is there a funny slang expression like "chicken" in French?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

*[Poule mouillée](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/poule_mouill%C3%A9e)* (lit. “wet hen”) is close: it means a person who lacks courage. It isn't as widely applicable as *chicken*: you can't use it as an adjective, and it's not as natural as in English to use it as an interjection (though you can say “*Espèce de poule mouillée !*”, which is roughly equivalent to “You [are] chicken!”). It is usually constructed as “*X est une poule mouillée*”.
For example, a child might launch a race and taunt the other children by saying “*le dernier arrivé est une poule mouillée*”.

Where English children would shout “Chicken!”, I think French children would shout “*oh, le peureux*”. Another childish phrase that's close is “*t'es pas cap'*” (short for *capable*), meaning “you don't dare” (and hence can translate “I dare you”).

Comment: _Poule mouillée_ has for me an hint of cowardice, which @codious doesn't seem to want.

Comment: @Un francophone: I think what he wants is a word which won't be taken seriously.

Comment: Quelques [autres adjectifs courants](http://www.cnrtl.fr/synonymie/poule%20mouill%C3%A9e/substantif): froussard, lâche, poltron.

Comment: @Unfrancophone The way I understand the question, the problem with *coward* is not the meaning but the intensity: *coward* is serious, can be insulting; *chicken* is more light-hearted, more playful.

Comment: Let's also take notice of the variant : *Dégonflé !*

Comment: I hear "mauviette" a lot

Comment: Trouillard, Mauviette, "Petit joueur", Couillon (belgicisme ?) , "Petite bite", Pétochard,... there's a lot of words that can be used, but indeed "Poule mouillée" is the closest translation...

Comment: I know this is really old, but as I see this answer is the most popular I must say that for me "Pouille mouillée" is not really slang and moreover is not really funny. I would say that only if I'm being really serious.

Answer (score 4):

Though regional and by no mean used throughout the Francophony, ***[pissou](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/pissou)*** is used in Quebec for this purpose, and while *poule mouillée* is well understood too (and I’ll agree it is figuratively closer to *chicken*), it is not as commonly used here. It is to be expected that slang will differ wildly from region to region, and I agree that in any case, *poule mouillée* will be a very good choice.

But in a Quebec setting, and if the aim of the translation is to sound natural and native, not necessarily to keep the hen, *pissou* could be a very appropriate choice.

According to [this article](http://www.dufrancaisaufrancais.com/le-pissou-quebecois/), the word came into French from the Langue d’oïl, and originally designated someone that needs to pee *(pisser)* often, or also a child that still pee in bed. This acceptation is dated in all regions of the Francophony, but a regional acceptation similar to what *chicken* is in English eventually emerged in Quebec¹, and is still widely used up to this day.

> <sub><sup>1</sup> I tend to think of it as a claim that in front of even a small danger, the *pissou* pee himself/herself, but I could not back it up with any type of document, so it remains open as to how it actually came into being.</sub>

Here is an example from *Le cahier rouge* of Michel Tremblay, Quebec’s most famous contemporary writer, putting in the mouth of a drag queen why he’d rather dress as a lady than as a man:

> Me voyez-vous d'ici ? Habillée en bûcheron avec les baguettes en l'air ? Le cul trop serré dans le seul jean que j'ai ? Épilée ? La queue de cheval sur l'épaule ? La petite démarche gondolante ? En gars, j'ai l'air fif; en fille, j'ai un peu plus l'air d'un être humain... J'me suis fait assez taper dessus quand j'étais à l'école pour m'enlever toute envie d'essayer d'avoir l'air d'un gars. Quand chuis en fille, je peux me défendre, y a rien qui me fait peur; pas quand chuis en gars. Quand chuis en gars, chuis un **pissou**, rien d'autre.

Comment: On le trouve aussi au [Glossaire](http://bibnum2.banq.qc.ca/bna/numtxt/179630.pdf) ainsi que _pisseux/pisseuse_ (_pissieux_ Picardie semble-t-il) qu'on dit de même sens, celui ou celle qui « recule », de pisser pour reculer nous dit-on. J'étais certain d'avoir entendu l'un ou l'autre ou _pissette_ dans le doublage québécois de _Slapshot_ (1977), et c'est finalement _pisseuse_ (34:40), et c'est qu'ils ont doublé les voix des enfants du journaliste et ils se disputent et le petit gars dit ça à la petite fille ! Merci !

Comment: J'ai dû aller voir pour comprendre qu'il s'agissait de reculer → devant le danger ←, je précise donc pour ceux qui se poseront aussi la question. Merci pour la recherche, le lien et l'exemple cinématographique.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to be rude while talking to a really close friend you could say "tapette" or "t'es une tapette !" which also stands for gay.

Don't use that if that person is actually gay, that would really be homophobic.

Example:

> — On va courir ?
>   — T'es fou il pleut !
>   — Tapette !

Comment: Of course, it's a lot more fun to use with actual gay people (*really* close friends, of course).

Comment: This usage is technically homophobic *whether or not* the person is actually gay, in fact. It is just safer to be homophobic when no gay people are around, if I somewhat understand your point. Anyway, this was not considered offensing one or two decades back, but probably because most people just weren't aware it could be an issue for anyone. Like Nikana says though, gay people with a sense of humour don't take offense on this, moreover when it's said by someone they know being broad-minded.

Comment: This expression entered in the common language some years ago, when people weren't looking everywhere for so-called homophobia. It isn't homophobic to use it as making a blonde-joke isn't a blonde-hate act, but indeed within the politically correct atmosphere nowadays, better use another expression which for sure won't hurt any community.

Answer (score 3):

There's another (mostly childish but not only) slang term that hasn't been mentionned yet :

> T'es un *trouillard* ! / Oh, le *trouillard* !

It's very commonly used, and never to refer to someone with a "legitimate" or understandable fear. Its use implies that the scare is clearly disproportionnate to the real threat.

(However, let's note that it fails to match the use of *chicken* in the expression *to play chicken*.)

Comment: I totally agree with you, much more "childish" and less "serious", just as the OP seems to need.

Answer (score 1):

There is a wonderful film starring Marion Cotillard called (I think) *Jeux d'enfants*, in which two kids play a game of chicken throughout their lives. The expression they use (I think) is '*cap pas cap*'. The English title of the film is 'Love Me if you Dare', so you get the feeling.

Answer (score 1):

*t'a la frousse ?* means "are you (too) scared to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that recentely more and more people (me included) started to use the word 
" canard " ( = duck ) exactly like english people use "chicken" , to mean that someone is not very brave in funny slang.

Answer (score 0):

It’s dated and probably more “cowardly” and less funny than you wanted, but the “faux-ami,” “[**Capon/(caponne)**](http://dictionnaire.reverso.net/francais-definition/caponne)” (without the “H” in "[chapon](http://dictionary.reverso.net/french-definition/chapon)"), works as both an adjective and a noun to communicate the idea of “a chicken/poulet (the animal) being afraid” in one word.